# How to block email if sender doesn't match reply-to address? [postfix]

Tags: linux, debian, email, postfix, spam

Currently our company is getting more and more spam. For a small company we had to block all incoming spam from chinese IPs, which blocks around 500 spams per week which is alot, as we're a local company we don't really need any contact from a chinese ISP so we're alright with it.

In the meantime it's not enough yet to get ride of all this spam. Currently we still receive spam from AOL servers. As few people might use these, I cannot simply reject them.

So I came up with an idea, as the spam always comes like this

```
from: spammer@server.com
reply-to:spammer@anotherserver.com
to:email@example.com
```

I was thinking about rejecting all emails who don't match both from and reply-to.

Then I figured out that I couldn't get it done that easy, because some of major support companies use a different reply-to address.

So I was thinking to add a rule to block incoming email if sender and reply-to doesn't match at all.

Something like this:

```
From: agent@server.com
Reply-to: agent@anotherserver.com
REJECT
```

and:

```
From: agent@server.com
Reply-to: agent@service.server.com or another_agent@server.com
ACCEPT
```

Did anyone tried to implement such rule? If yes how could I do this using a sender.pcre on a postfix server?

Thank you

Comment: That would break my emails, since I use address extensions/aliases to make the user part based on which company I'm working with - so the "from" might be "me@mine" and the reply-to might be "me-yourco@mine".  Seems like using the common and well known SPF records, DKIM, etc. may be better than based on what is on the mail envelope.

Comment: Hi thank for your comment, I guess it wouldn't break since @mine is the same, so it would be ok. Unless it was from me'@'mine and the reply-to was me-yourco'@'another

Comment: perhaps u should look for a framework like rspamd https://rspamd.com/features.html
or try set up postgrey, amavis-new and other tools see this article:
[wiki.semarkit.net](https://wiki.semarkit.net/index.php/Postfix_%2B_Amavis-NEW_%2B_Spamassassin_%2B_ClamAV_%2B_SPF_%2B_Postgrey_%2B_DKIM_%2B_DMARC) I hope that helps

Comment: rspamd seems interesting, I'll do some research on it. Thank you